# How .do extension is appended in the URL in struts?

Tags: struts1

I am new to struts and as far as i know that .do extension causes the tomcat to call the action servlet and action servlet has resource process object that invokes a particular action class

But lets suppose we have a jsp page

first.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="s" %>
 <s:form action="myform">...
```

when we submit this form

action-mapping in struts.config.xml is called and it picks from there as:

```
<action input="/first.jsp" name="actionformbean" path="/myform" scope="session"
   type="actionclass"/>
```

whenever http://....myform.do is encountered, tell the resource process object of the action servlet to invoke actionclass

BUT how is action mapping related to servlet mapping(as url pattern .do is given in here ?)

I am confused with this .do, that how is it appended to the url :(

HELP plz
thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard Action Servlet mapping for Struts is defined in your web.xml, the deployment descriptor. It goes like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet-name is defined earlier in the deployment descriptor:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     ...
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  ...
</servlet>
```

The url-pattern binds all urls ending with `.do` to the Action Servlet. The Action Servlet in turn delegates all calls to the responsible action.

Now, there are action mappings like the one you mention:

```
<action input="/first.jsp" name="actionformbean" path="/myform" scope="session"
   type="actionclass"/>
```

Action mappings have a path that specifies their URL. The URL doesn't need a .do suffix because Struts already "knows" it was called, otherwise the action mapping itself couldn't be executed. Once the specified action is executed, it silently appends a .do suffix since only URL with those suffixes will be matched - otherwise the next request would be lost.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but you have written that url-pattern binds all urls ending with .do to action servlet. I am still confused is how .do will be appended to the url

Comment: i am not ble to understand this line:-  since only URL with those suffixes will be matched - "otherwise the next request would be lost". What do you mean by next request?

Answer (score 1):

> "Thanks for the reply, but you have written that url-pattern binds all urls ending with .do to action servlet. I am still confused is how .do will be appended to the url"

The `.do` is automatically appended by default by the Struts Frame work(Hope it's been done by `ActionServlet` itself). If you wish to change the extension(say .abc), then you should modify the action value accordingly (as `action="actionsomthing.abcd"`).

**Corrections are appreciated**