# Why do we typecast ActionForm object into our java form bean class in Action class in STRUTS?

Tags: struts, struts-1

What i know: actionformbean that we create is a sub class of ActionForm

Now let's suppose we create...
Struts action form bean: productbean.java
Struts action class:     productaction.java

In productaction.java's `execute()` method:- I did

```
{
productbean p1 = new productbean();
String n =p1.getName();   // calling the getter, that returns the product name 
}
```

But n is null, when written into database

With this in `execute` method everything works fine:

```
{
productbean p1 = (productbean)form; // downcasting of ActionForm object
String n = p1.getName(); 
}
```

My question is if actionclass and formbean are in same package, why can't we just create an object of the formbean and call its getter function in actionclass? Why downcasting of ActionForm object  is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you create a new ProductBean instance and get the name from this new instance, you will always get the default value of the name property (null, typically), instead of the value that was extracted from the `name` request parameter, stored into the ProductBean instance that Struts has created and has passed to the `execute()` method of your action.

When a request comes in for your action, Struts instantiates the form bean, populates it with the request parameters, and invokes your action with the form bean. If you create another form bean instance, it will not get magically populated with the request parameters.

What you're doing is similar to the following:

- ask someone (Struts) to write their name on a sheet of paper and to give you this sheet of paper
- take another blank sheet of paper, read what's written on this blank sheet of paper, and be surprised not to find the name written by Struts.

Comment: I got it that you are saying is when action is called it already instantiates our bean so no point in creating a new instance.                           But in dis example:I think its same but not sure :s                                                  class A{  } ........                                                             class B extends A{  }  ...............................                                               public class ex{main(){A p = new A(); B p1 =(B)p; }}..........                 casting error comes in this case, why not this error comes in ActionForm's object

Comment: Because what Struts instantiates is a ProductBean (which is also an ActionForm since it extends ActionForm). So casting it to ProductBean is OK. To rephrase your example, what Struts does is rather: `A p = new B(); B p1 = (B) p;`. And in this case, there is no error.

Comment: Thanx for replying but i have 1 more doubt: if we do'System.out.println(p);' after the statement'A p = new B();'.... it prints B@56sd... that means there is no downcasting happening here ? Since we are casting the object to B but it's already B

Comment: casting to B is just that: You have a B object, but its referenced as an A, so you cast it to B to have the reference as a B. Casting doesn't transform the object. It will always fail if the casted object is not already a B. When you do `Fruit f = new Banana();`, f is a fruit, of type Banana. You may cast it to Banana, because it's a banana. Trying to cast it to Apple will of course fail, because the fruit you have is not an apple, but a banana.

Comment: ooh i remember that animal dog example now :P, Its like java web and core java have teamed up against me :(... but still thanks alot sir/mam for your help now i am crystal clear about the casting in my example :D

Comment: Then you should mark the answer as helpful by clicking the Up triangle next to the answer, and mark it accepted (because it's the best answer you had and it fixed your problem) by clicking the tick symbol next to the answer. That's how you reward those who help you here.

Comment: i still have to reach 15 reputation to vote up but i marked it as answer. Thanks again !

Comment: can you help me with this too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371683/how-do-extension-is-appended-in-the-url-in-struts